# Numpy | How to get image array of specific form

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I have a folder containing images and I want to read them in as numpy arrays with shape `(picture_number, height, width, channel)`

```
import numpy as np

height = 200
width = 300
channels = 3
images = 1000
scene_length = 10
data = np.random.random((images, height, width, channels))
```

see the radom data set.

> **Question 1**: How can I read in my images such that I get such an array?

now I want to reshape the array such that it looks like `(scene_number, frame, height, width, channel)`. Every scene is consisting of `scene_length` frames.

> **Question 2**: What is the best way to achive this with numpy?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, assuming your files are in
`p = Path(r'C:\imagefolder')`
make a list `fn_list` with your filenames and read your images into a list. For example:

`fn_list= list(p.glob("./*.jpg"))`

then use scipy.ndimage library to read them into a list of ndarrays:

`list_np_images=[scipy.ndimage.imread(f, flatten=False) for f in fn_list]`, then use `np.swapaxes` to put the image axis at the end.